# Create table with constraint based on another column

Tags: insert

Say a database has the following tables:

- `movie(id, title, rent_period)`
- `customer(id, name)`

I would like to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE rental (
   movie_id int,
   customer_id int,
   rent_date date,
   return_date date,
   FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
   PRIMARY KEY rental_pk (movie_id, customer_id)
)
```

Can I make make the `return_date` field be populated automatically as `rental(rent_date) + movie(rent_period)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using a trigger on your rental table. Trigger before insert - set the return_date column value to be the rent_date value in the data being saved, plus look up the value of movie.rent_period based on the movie_id value being saved.